# Exclude external javascript file from loading

Tags: php, javascript

I have a problem. In layout.phtml I load javascript file which I need in all pages except few:

> $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath('js.js'), 'text/javascript');
>
> echo $this->headScript()

How can I exclude this javascript in index.phtml file which uses layout.phtml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
if (__FILE__ != $YOUR_PATH_NAME) {
  $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath('js.js'), 'text/javascript');
  echo $this->headScript()
}
```

Replace `$YOUR_PATH_NAME` with the actual path. This script should execute snippet inside if block only if it's not on the  index page